# GetUserNameEx fails with error 1114 (ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED)

Tags: windows, dll

I've shell extension for right click in Explorer. On certain machine with win 7 Ent SP1, GetUserNameEx called from QueryContextMenu() fails with GetLastError returning ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED. It was seen that GetUserName API also fails with same error code. The machine has alockout.dll (MS accout lockout tool) present on it.

Process monitor and Process Explorer do not indicate any sign of failure. Secur32.dll and alockout.dll were loaded successfully in Explorer (as seen from Process Explorer). When alockout.dll is not present, things work fine, i.e. GetUserNameEx returns the user name.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong over here? How to troubleshoot such problem? (any tool available to diagnose this problem further)

Note:
1. Similar post was already seen on MS blog with no response:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/983b5bec-dfe1-4f85-8123-86ec715ba484/when-getusernameex-fails-with-error-code-1114-errordllinitfailed

1. Discussed on CodeGuru forum. However, the solution/workaround used here cannot be used in my case.
   http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?517108-GetUserNameEx-returning-1114

Comment: Um, you shouldn't be running alockout.dll in production. It is only for troubleshooting account lockout problems and should be uninstalled as soon as the investigation is over. The workaround is to remove alockout.dll. As noted in the documentation for alockout.dll, it uses AppInit_DLLs, which should really be called [`Deadlock_Or_Crash_Randomly_DLLs`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/13/6648400.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. If alockout.dll is required in production, is there any way to find out what exactly is causing this error? I used depends.exe tool (the profiling option) for Explorer.exe. However, it was not that convenient in my case(because it stopped profiling automatically when Explorer.exe exited (somehow) and did not allow me to profile to a point where I could right click in explorer). Is there any other tool which would help me troubleshoot further on this error?

Comment: If alockout.dll is required in production, then you are screwed because `AppInit_DLLs` can cause apps to fail randomly. `depends.exe` will not help because it studies only static dependencies, and `AppInit_DLLs` is not only a dynamic dependency, it's a dynamic dependency *that isn't even in the code being analyzed*. It's just a Hand of God that reaches in and screws with your process. If you really want to debug this, you need to turn on loader snaps and see what DLL failed to initialize. But I reiterate that you are not in a supported configuration.